# Python Plotly: Visualizing and plotting normal distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

To plot Normal distribution curve for error data, I currently plot it like this,

```
mymean = np.mean(mydata)
mystd = np.std(mydata)
mypd = scipy.stats.norm.pdf((mydata), mymean, mystd)
plt.plot(mydata, mypd)
```

## The result of my code

[image]

The result is very bad,
Is there any alternative to effectively visualize curves in PLOTLY or matplotlib, like the one shown in image below (at-least with sigma values).

Any solution better than the my result would be great! Thanks

## Normal distribution curve

[image]

## edit1 :new result

Sorted using: 
`df.sort_values('mydata', inplace=True)`

But still not a good visualization like *normal distribution curve(sigma values)*

[image]

Comment: You need to sort your data.

Comment: sorted as in edit 1, but didn't help much @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Well, "didn't help much" is relative... I mean you now have a nice curve instead of great chaos, which is what I would indeed call "much". Now you may start adding your text labels and colorfill as desired.